# How to Angularjs take the value of the widget calendar?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, calendar, widget

By using the datetimepicker to enter the date in the input, the ng-model is not capturing the date entered by the calendar button. The ng-model capturing this only if I insert such a space on the date entered by the calendar button.
Anyone know tell me how do I by pressing the calendar button the ng-model capture the value?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/datetimepicker.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <table ng-app="">
        <td>
            <div id="data1" class="input-group date">
               <input id="data1" name="data1" ng-change="data1" ng-model="data1" type="text" />
               <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
               <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               $("#data1").datetimepicker({
                    minView: 2,
                    autoclose: true,
                    language: 'pt',
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    showMeridian: true,
                    startView: 2}).find('input').addClass("form-control");
            </script>
        </td>
        <td><p ng-bind="data1"></p></td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should render `datetimepicker` or any jquery plugin through directive only because directive provide good element(DOM) level control & binding. `datepicker` didn't update the value of `ng-model` automati, You need to update that value manually of respective `ng-model` using `ngModel.$setViewValue(val.date);` on change event of `datetimepicker` i.e. `dp.change` event.

**HTML**

```
<input name="data1" datetimepicker ng-model="data1" type="text" />
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('datetimepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.datetimepicker();
            element.on('dp.change',function(val){
                ngModel.$setViewValue(val.date);
                scope.$apply()
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/umktjpLa/9/)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the help, however, after the change, the widget stopped working.

Comment: After the change in the code, it was so with error of `TypeError: undefined is not a function`: Changed: `<script type="text/javascript">
 var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
 app.directive('datetimepicker', function() {...` and input `<table ng-app="myapp">...<input datetimepicker id="data1"  ng-model="data1" type="text" />`

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. The link [http://jsfiddle.net/rafaelcb21/umktjpLa/] is the Datetimepicker the code. In this code the tag `<p ng-bind="data1"></p>` is not getting the value chosen in the `ng-model="data1"`

Comment: @rafaelcb21 Feeling glad to help you. Learned a lots of thing while doing this. Thanks for such question :)